# Compare goodness of two estimations

Tags: regression, method-comparison

I have performed two estimations with the following results:

[image: Graphs of the two models]

- *Blue line:* Result of a simple linear regression on the displayed data points ($\approx$ the truth).
- *Red line:* Result of an estimation with different data.

How can I assess the goodness of the *red estimation* (in comparison to the *blue*)?

Comment: It depends on what matters for you. Perhaps mean square error?

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you! Actually, I am not sure, what *could* matter for me? My aim is to assess the goodness of the *red way* to gain an estimation for the data points.

Comment: I don't know enough about what you're trying to do, what a suitable loss function might be for your problem. I suggested a common measure of goodness of fit (mean square error), which would be a reasonable way to measure discrepancy between the red line and the data.

Comment: @Glen_b The *MSE* for the *blue line* is $1.05$ and for the *red line* $1.33$. I am unsure how to interpret these values: $0$ would be the best, but I do not know the upper limit of the interval (like when using $R^2$). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just in case, it helps to understand the question a bit better, some more information: The data points in the graph above are (*market share* / *sales*) obtained through a survey. Unfortunately, the *sales* are not public in general. Therefore, I have devised a way to estimate the sales by assuming an underlying distribution (keyword *long tail*) and making use of publicly available data (e. g., *market share*, *cumulative sales*, etc.). The result of this estimation is the red line. Now, I would like to assess analytically *how* good / reliable this method is.

Comment: @Glen_b I have solved the *interpretation problem*. Although, if you have any new idea concerning my opening question caused by my previous comment, I would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: You could perhaps write an answer to your own question, then. I'm not exactly sure what you're referring to with the second sentence of that last comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to measure the goodness of fit of both lines is using the *Mean Squared Error* (*MSE*) and *Root Mean Squared Error* (*RMSE*):

$$MSE = \frac{1}{n} \centerdot \sum \left( \hat{y}_i - y_i \right)^2$$
$$RMSE = \sqrt{MSE}$$

*RMSE* indicates the average error and equals $0$ in the best case. Furthermore, it is suitable to compare the precision of the *red* and the *blue line* by comparing their *RMSE* values.